# getApplicationContext() and intent filters

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm making a pdf file viewer app with [this](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) library. I applied other things successfully, but I'm continuously failing to link the app with "Complete action using" list of Android.

First, `init()` method of the library is as follows(MainActivity.java):

```
private void init() {
    lv_pdf = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_pdf);
    dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    fn_permission();

    lv_pdf.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PdfActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", i);
            startActivity(intent);
            Log.e("Position", i + "");
        }
    });
}
```

Second, AndroidManifest.xml file is as follows:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".PdfActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

MainActivity.java defines permission and start screens of the app, and PdfActivity.java shows content of the pdf files.

**The Problem:**

`init()` method have a implicit intent with `getApplicationContext()`. How to I link this to intent filter in AndroidManifest.xml file? I want to launch the app through "Complete action using" screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too can you use it
Intent intent = new (this, PdfActivity.class);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getApplicationContext() use MainActivity.this